# How to close Uri file after editing

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am using webBrowser in Windows Forms to edit a text file.

I can save the file via the dialog, but I don't know how to tell the webBrowser control to unload the document?

So that if I press button again it will open the saved file again.

```
 private void EditDates_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (EditDates.Text.StartsWith("Close"))
            {
                webBrowser1.ShowSaveAsDialog();
                EditDates.Text = "Edit Dates";
                webBrowser1.Document.CLOSE????

            }
            else
            {

                EditDates.Text = "Close Dates";
                webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(@"H:\EOD\ProductionDates.txt");
                webBrowser1.Document.ExecCommand("EditMode", false, null);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (EditDates.Text.StartsWith("Close"))
{
  webBrowser1.ShowSaveAsDialog();
  EditDates.Text = "Edit Dates";
  webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("about:blank");
}
```